# Quantification under sumbool

Tags: coq

I have found it quite difficult to work with goals of the form

`{forall _, _} + { not (forall _, _) }`

Consider this for a minimal example:

```
Inductive X := a | b.

Proposition X_q_dec :
  forall P : X -> Prop,
    (forall x, { P x } + { not (P x) }) ->
    { forall x, P x } + { not (forall x, P x) }.
Proof.
  intros.
  pose proof H a as Ha.
  pose proof H b as Hb.
  destruct Ha, Hb.
  left; destruct x; assumption.
  all: right; intro C; auto.
Qed.
```

Since `X` has a finite number of elements, there is a finite number of decidable predicates on it. Thus in this proof I just look over all of them and prove the correct side of sumbool for each one.

However, in the more general case, *I cannot move the goal at all*:

```
Proposition nat_q_dec :
  forall P : nat -> Prop,
    (forall n, { P n } + { not (P n) }) ->
    { forall n, P n } + { not (forall n : nat, P n) }.
```

My gut feeling is that this should be undecidable: there is no algorithm with a finite upper boundary on operations required to determine whether or not `P` holds on all `n : nat`. The same, it seems, should apply to any other type with an infinite number of elements (i.e. not just `nat`). Unfortunately, my theoretical background falls short to provide a rigorous argument about this.

Is my feeling correct?

If so, why exactly?

If not, how should I go about proving such a goal in Coq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, and the argument is pretty much what you laid out.  Suppose that `P t n` means that "the lambda term `t` can be normalized using at most `n` reduction steps".  Then `~ P t n` should be decidable for every `n`, but it is not the case that we can decide `forall n, ~ P t n`, since this would imply solving the halting problem.